# Where can I find more information about custom/extension attributes in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, attributes

I want to be able use a script to write/read from extensionAttribute1-15

I was wondering where I could find more info about the size of these fields, what can be written into them. I've used google, but I dont think I'm either searching for the right thing, or I just can't find anything.

Anyone helpe me out?

Answer (score 1):

If you load and use ADSIEdit from the admin tools, you can view the schema for more information.  In the meantime, look here for more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms980473(v=exchg.65).aspx.  It appears to be a Unicode string

Answer (score 1):

For length, see the optional *rangeUpper* attribute that is associated with the ms-Exch-Extension-Attribute-1 attribute.

For Unicode strings, rangeUpper specifies the maximum number of characters.  In the case of the ms-Exch-Extension-Attribute-1 attribute, it is 1024 characters.

The type of the attribute is determined by the combination of the attributeSyntax (2.5.5.12) and the omSyntax (64).  In this case, a unicode string.

The attribute is replicated to the global catalog (isMemberOfPartialAttributeSet=true)

**[MS-ADTS]: Active Directory Technical Specification: 3.1.1.2.2.2 LDAP Representations**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223177%28v=prot.13%29.aspx

**Attributes Added by Exchange**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms869146%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx

**ms-Exch-Extension-Attribute-1 Attribute**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms980473%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx